# Spring MVC - RequestBody not working (JSON)

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, marshalling

I'm having a simple controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void postCheck(@RequestBody TestDTO testDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {

System.out.println(testDTO);

}
```

the DTO is:

```
public class TestDTO {

private String hello;

public TestDTO() {

}

public String getHello() {
    return hello;
}

public void setHello(String hello) {
    this.hello = hello;
}
```

}

When i try to post a request to that url i get an ERROR 400 Message response "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." (the controller method is not being invoked at all)

I tried posting from Chrome's poster plugin AND from jquery's ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/NG_Admin/test",
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "json",      
    data : JSON.stringify(eval({"hello" : "world"})),
    error : function(data) {
        alert('Error');
    },
    success : function(data) {  
            alert('Success!');
    }
});
}
```

Any ideas? (btw I use both   'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.12', 'jackson-core-asl', version:'1.9.12')

Thanks

Comment: does it work when you remove `consumes = ...` from `@RequestMapping` - Annotation? I have a somewhat matching setup here (spring 3.2.4, jackson 1.9.12, jquery post from frontend, only extended by using direct validation for my formmodel/dto, too), only missing the consumes - and it works like a charm. But... I see you stringify some strings in json from clientside... might be this, too. I would try to remove the `""`

Comment: Still not working:( Do I have to configure spring to work with jackson? or is it happening automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,I fixed the problem,

Had to add a filter for all request that handles CORS access.

Comment: Adding a little more about the filters might help others. Please update.